# Can I change the Firefox menu to look like the Firefox menu in Windows?

Tags: firefox, windows-7, themes

Why Firefox's main menu is different in Ubuntu (10.04) and windows 7 ? Is different main theme?.

Can I change the Ubuntu Firefox menu to look like windows 7 menu?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Right Click to the right of the menu and untick Menu Bar.

[image]

Now it will have a win7 type menu.

[image]

Comment: That is nice, but... is there any way to also load the FF button and its tabs in the title bar? This way you save 1 more bar.

Comment: @MestreLion webupd8.org/2011/03/firefox-4-get-tabs-in-title-bar-like.html

Comment: This doesn't work anymore :(

Answer (score 8):

To activate the new Firefox 4 layout with the "Firefox" button replacing the menu bar, uncheck View ---> Toolbars ---> Menubar.

But in Linux you will get just a plain grey button instead a orange one like in Windows.
But there are several fixes:

- http://userstyles.org/styles/43590/firefox-4-menu-button-v2-linux (requires Stylish Addon)
- http://userstyles.org/styles/43513/firefox-4-menu-windows-look-alike-linux (requires Stylish Addon)
- https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/themed-button-for-linux/ (Stand-alone Addon)

Answer (score 3):

You can go further than just unchecking the Menu Bar (though this is the first step). Simply install the [Movable Firefox Button](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/movable-firefox-button/) extension and you get a nicer button that you can move all over the place.

I stick mine on the right of the tabs because I only use it very rarely

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
#appmenu-toolbar-button {
  list-style-image: url("chrome://branding/content/icon16.png");
}
#appmenu-toolbar-button > .toolbarbutton-text,
#appmenu-toolbar-button > .toolbarbutton-menu-dropmarker {
  display: none !important;
}
```

This trick is for Ubuntu only (because that is all I have tested it out on, you can try other linux distributions but will not work on Windows):

- When you hide the menu bar as suggested by M. Night Shyamalan, you can have just the firefox icon in its place instead of the "Firefox" that's default for Ubuntu like the picture attached below.
- Paste the above code into your chrome file that is located in your firefox profile folder; if no such file exists you'll have to create it.  Location `"/home/USER/.mozilla/firefox/PROFILE-NAME/chrome/userChrome.css"`, open it with a text-editor, the paste the above mentioned code and save, and restart firefox.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 13.4 you must first disable the `Global Menu Bar Integration` extension. It's found under `Tools -> Addons -> Extensions`. After restarting Firefox you must disable the `Menu Bar` under `View -> Toolbars`.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a style to make the button look like this:

[image]

But for obvious reasons, it only works for IceWeasel. However, if you want to use it on firefox, you can edit the xcf file located in button/source directory.

Here's the download link, just extract it on your chrome folder (~/.mozilla/firefox/thatshitendedin.default/chrome/).

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/88421827/button.tar.gz

Comment: how does this answer the question?