# Where is firefox button for Firefox 4 for ubuntu?

Tags: 10.10, firefox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I change the Firefox menu to look like the Firefox menu in Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32395/can-i-change-the-firefox-menu-to-look-like-the-firefox-menu-in-windows)

I have just installed Firefox 4 from the Ubuntu software center, but I don't see new Firefox button.
Is it removed for the Ubuntu version? If not how do I make it visible?