# Is it possible to make Firefox look like in Windows in Lubuntu?

Tags: windows, firefox, appearance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I change the Firefox menu to look like the Firefox menu in Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32395/can-i-change-the-firefox-menu-to-look-like-the-firefox-menu-in-windows)

[image]

I guess that does not make sense in Unity, because it has a special way of changing the classical display of the Main Menu and to disable the option of un/checking it.

[image]

In Windows, after hiding Main Menu, Firefox creates that upper-left button that has become the image of Firefox 4+, but in Lubuntu un-checking the Main Menu would not have this effect, but would result in the looks common to Firefox 3.6.

Is that  new look available somehow in Lubuntu?

[image]
(default theme)

[image]
(REIN theme)

Comment: Do you want only the button instead of the whole menu?

Comment: yes, i'm under the impression that is not as obvious as in windows

Comment: In my opinion, This question is not a duplicate, because the other question asking for only Firefox button, but the OP here know how to enable the button, He wants to know how to add other toolbar icons too. In other words, it is a broader question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Though I'm not 100% sure what you asked, but I think, you are asking to change firefox menu to shrink in a button, like in Windows*

To do so,

1. Go to *Tools* → *Add-ons* and in the **Extensions** section, disable the **Ubuntu Firefox modification** extension and then restart Firefox.
2. After restarting Firefox, go to the Firefox Menu → *View* → *Toolbars*  and unselect the  *Menu bar*. (remove the tick mark)

   To revert the change: Click on the Firefox button → *Preferences* and select the *Menu bar*.

   **Before**
   [image]

   **After**
   [image]
3. Then to add the other buttons like the Windows version of firefox,

   - Go to *View* → *Toolbars* and then *Customize...*. (If you have the old menu enabled)
   - Or Click on the Firefox button, Go to *Preference* → *Toolbar Layout...* (If you have Windows like Firefox button enabled)
   - From the new **Customize toolbar** Window, drag and drop the desired buttons from it to the Firefox toolbars. Also you can drag the right most home icon to the left.

   The result is like below:

   [image]

   You see that, I have added

   - a forward button,
   - a seperator,
   - home button moved to the left side
   - Download button,
   - Bookmarks button,
   - and the history button.

Comment: i your sure? sorry to say that but i cannot test that for the moment (no ubuntu sys for a couple of days) and i'm under the impression  that just hiding main menu does not provide the button but just hides the menu as in firefox 3.6. that's why i asked the question, as i knew the procedure of not displaying the menu (see question)

Comment: This works in Windows, but for some reason the "Menu bar" option does not even appear in Ubuntu 12.04's current version of Firefox, at least not when using Unity.

Comment: I can confirm that this works in Lubuntu. The menu bar is replaced by a "Firefox" button. I edited the answer with a comparison of the two modes.